# find the last two digits of this number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

find the last 2 digits of this number 
$$19^{{17}^{{{{15}^{{\ddots}}}^{{3}^{1}}}}}$$

PS: the three dots in opposite direction .

NOW I know that I should work on  $mod 100$ but I couldn't work with this very big number !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quick to compute the order of $19$ mod $100$, since $19^5 \equiv -1 \pmod{100}$.  That is, the order is $10.$  So you really just need to know the last digit of the exponent.

The order of $17$ mod $10$ is $4$.  So we just need to know the residue of the exponent on $17$ modulo $4$.

Well, $15 \equiv -1 \pmod{4}$ and it's raised to an odd power, so the part of the exponent starting with $15$ reduces to $-1 \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$.  So we need $17^3 \equiv (-3)^3 \equiv 3 \pmod{10}$.

That is, the exponent on $19$ is $10k+3$ for some $k$, and $19^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod{100}$, so the answer is $19^3 \equiv 6859 \equiv 59 \pmod{100}$.